# conky drives info, changing totalbar colours under certain conditions

Tags: conky

I have a conky script displaying drives info, percentage used, 
current amount used and total size

I have a total bar under each drive name and I want to change the colour
to red if the total is greater than 90%

For the highest cpu/mem sections I am running top command for top4 processes and setting top1 to red

Do i need some sort of if statement to do this with the total bar for drives? Not sure how to do if statements in conky.

[image]

here is my current script

```
use_xft yes
xftfont 123:size=8
xftalpha 0.1
update_interval 1
total_run_times 0

own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0

double_buffer yes
#minimum_size 250 5
#maximum_width 500
draw_shades no
draw_outline yes
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_color 000000
default_shade_color 000000
default_outline_color 99ddff

alignment top_left
gap_x 0
gap_y 320
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 1
override_utf8_locale yes
use_spacer yes


minimum_size 0 0
TEXT
${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=25}
${color }CPU:  ${color }$cpu% 
${color 99ddff}${cpubar 5,150}
${color }MEM:  ${color }$memperc% $mem/$memmax
${color 99ddff}${membar 5,150}

${color }SWAP: ${color }$swapperc% $swap/$swapmax
${color 99ddff}${swapbar 5,150}
${color }ROOT: ${color }${fs_used_perc /}% ${fs_free /}/${fs_size /}
${color 99ddff}${fs_bar 5,150 /}
${color }HOME: ${color }${fs_used_perc /home/brian/}% ${fs_free /home/brian/}/${fs_size /home/brian/}
${color 99ddff}${fs_bar 5,150 /home/brian/}
${color }MOVIES: ${color }${fs_used_perc /media/brian/Movies/}% ${fs_free /media/brian/Movies/}/${fs_size /media/brian/Movies/}
${color 99ddff}${fs_bar 5,150 /media/brian/Movies}
${color }ANIME: ${color }${fs_used_perc /media/brian/Anime/}% ${fs_free /media/brian/Anime/}/${fs_size /media/brian/Anime/}
${color 99ddff}${fs_bar 5,150 /media/brian/Anime}
${color }TV SHOWS: ${color }${fs_used_perc /media/brian/Tv Shows/}% ${fs_free /media/brian/Tv Shows/}/${fs_size /media/brian/Tv Shows/}
${color 99ddff}${fs_bar 5,150 /media/brian/Tv Shows}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Conky object `if_match` is the key. For example...

```
${if_match ${fs_used_perc /media/brian/Tv Shows/} > 90}${color red}${else}${color 99ddff}${endif}${fs_bar 5,150 /media/brian/Tv Shows}
```

See `man conky` for more info.